# Flutter: Get list of all Near by WiFi networks

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, networkextension, nehotspothelper

I am working on one `IoT` application, and I have to connect my `IoT` device with the wifi network using Flutter application similar to `Google Home`, `Amazon Echo`, and `Alexa`. For the same, I required all available wifi lists in the network. So Is it possible the get a list of all available Wifi list in Flutter?

In `Android`, Using the [wifi_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_flutter) and [wifi](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi) I am able to get the available wifi list. But I don't found any library or any solutions using which I can get the wifi list for `iOS Swift`.

[image]

Alexa App Screenshot:- https://ibb.co/f9zf2qn

Google Home App Screenshot:- https://ibb.co/B4WxvKd

Please write your answer with some code if you know any solution.

Comment: IMHO you just don't have required permittions on iOS.

Comment: do read this link: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/113765

Answer (score 1):

head to [wifi_iot](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot) i think it's enough to explain what is available right now.
Good Luck!